# Difference about byte-addressable memory address and memory in direct mapping

Tags: assembly, caching, memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Consider a computer uses 48-bit byte-addressable memory address, and it has a memory of 4 GB
and a one-level cache of 2 KB (not counting the space for tags nor dirty flags). Suppose a cache
block is composed of 32 words and a word consists of 4 B.

I am going to do direct mapping but I am not sure about the length of the physical address is 48-bit or 32-bit (4GB = 2^32) ?

It would be great if you can explain the difference about byte-addressable memory address and memory meaning here.

Tag: ?
Block: 4 (2^4 cache block)
Offset: 7

Comment: Why do you have a 48-bit address if you only have 4 GB of address space?

Comment: If your CPU supports 48-bit physical addresses but your system only has 4GiB of DRAM installed, it can still have PCIe device memory and MMIO ports at higher addresses.  And the cache tags have to be wide enough to support 48-bit physical addresses.  (Unless there's some weird limitation like only uncacheable pages / regions are supported outside the low 32 or 36 bits or whatever.  But if nothing is said about that, I'd assume the full range of physical address space works normally.  Especially in a computer architecture homework problem!)